# iPhone: Displaying custom view when notification is fired

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I am trying to display a custom view once a notification is fired on the iPhone. By that I mean, once the UILocalNotification alert pops up and the user presses the action button, right now it shows my main view but I'd rather have it show a different view.

How do I accomplish that? Don't necessarily need code, just the general steps to accomplish this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 - (void)application(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification
```

This is the method that gets fired once you click the action button on an alert dialog that was triggered by a UILocalNotification. Just had to show the view from there.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
```

UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocalNotificationKey in launchOptions
You use this key to access contents of the dictionary passed in the second parameter of the UIApplicationDelegate method application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:. It returns the UILocalNotification object associated with the local notification just presented to the application.

Then you can use the information you passed in the notification and show different view controller or any customised view

Comment: So let's say there's nothing that's passed with UILocalNotification, I just want a different view shown, I can basically use the above method as an 'Event Listener' and show my view of choice when the method is fired. Correct?

Comment: Actually, you can pass any object in the userInfo dictionary property of UILocalNotification. If you don't pass any thing which can help you show different view, yes, you can show your view of choice.

Comment: I have to unnaccept the answer. The method that fired for me is

    - (void)application(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification